# Does pandas Series.update() not really allow the index parameter?

Tags: python, pandas

In Pandas documentation for their Series.update function, they give the following example

```
s = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
s.update(pd.Series(['d', 'e'], index=[0, 2]))
s
0    d
1    b
2    e
dtype: object
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.update.html

But when I recreate a similar example, I get a TypeError that says
`Series.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'`

---

My Try, using pandas version 1.4.3:

```
INPUT:
ser = pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(ser)

OUTPUT:
0    a
1    b
2    c
dtype: object

INPUT:
replacer = pd.Series(['x','z'])
print(replacer)

OUTPUT:
0    x
1    z
dtype: object

INPUT:
ser.update(replacer, index=[0, 1])

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\somebody\projects\my_project\my_notebook.ipynb Cell 11 in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 ser.update(replacer, index=[0, 1])

TypeError: Series.update() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'
```

Is this 'index' keyword parameter just not implemented or is there something very obvious that I am not doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is **not** a bug. Look carefully at the brackets:

> s.update(pd.Series **(** ['d', 'e'], index=[0, 2] **)** )

They cover both the index **and** the "d" and "e". In your code you only bracketed the two letters without the index no. inside as well.

As @Tim_Roberts has mentioned, this is from the source codeand the function is:

```py
    def update(self, other) -> None:
```

This function has no `*args` and therefore you cannot simply use `index`on its own in the function.

Comment: This is it. I see now. The update function just automatically uses whatever index the replacer series already has. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a documentation bug.  In the source code, the function is defined as

```
    def update(self, other) -> None:
```

It doesn't even take an `*args` to allow for other options.  You might file a bug report.